why new added schema property reflects on returned mongodb documents?
I know that adding new property(s) in our mongoose schema won't reflect to existing data from our mongodb documents unless you do db.collection.update(...) so.
But why mongoose adds this new property(s) after you query them?
Route handler:
// base url endpoit /api/users
// router.get("/", getAllUsers)
async function getAllUsers(req, res) {
  const users = await User.find({})
  res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({
    success: true,
    data: {
      users: users
    }
  })
}

Adding a new property isAdmin:
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  ...
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: false
  }
}, { timestamps: true })

when I query/fetch them:

Edit:
Why mongoose inserts that isAdmin after receiving documents from query? It should return what the exact Binary jSON from our actual database without modifying it so we know that we forgot to update the existing documents, because let say in the future we go inside our mongodb and try to query documents based on that property like db.users.find({ isAdmin: false }), the documents without the isAdmin property would always be excluded unless you use null or undefined.

It sets the default value if the property is undefined in the document, and a default value is defined in the schema. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/defaults.html

@OnurDoğan why mongoose inserts that isAdmin after receiving documents from query? It should return what the exact Binary jSON from our actual database without modifying it so we know that we forgot to update the existing documents, because let say in the future we go inside our mongodb and try to query documents based on that property like db.users.find({ isAdmin: false }), the documents without the isAdmin property would always be excluded unless you use null or undefined.

If you don't want the default values appended then you need to use lean() so const users = await User.find({}).lean() which will skip hydrating the resulting documents and instead just return POJOs rather than fully fledged mongoose documents.

@jQueeny Yeah I already thought about using .lean() but all the mongoose methods will be gone from it and we need those methods on POST routes to create/modify mongodb documents after querying.

Yes unfortunately you would need to remove the default value from the schema then and enforce the isAdmin: false in your await Model.create({...}) or const doc = new Model({...}); await doc.save().

Mongoose doesn't deal in BSON, it uses Javascript.
When you execute await User.find({}):

mongoose builds a find command object in javascript
the underlying node.js driver converts the javascript command object to BSON
the driver sends the command to the server, and receives the response in BSON
the driver converts the BSON response to a javascript object, and returns it to mongoose
mongoose instantiates an object with something similar to new User(returned value)

If the definition of User is changed, i.e. by modifying the schema, that instantiation in the last step will use the new definition, so the missing isAdmin property will be given the default value of false.
